# Replacing the contents of a text file in java

Tags: java, output

I have a text file named leaderboard.txt, I load it up as a resource stream and read the contents to a string (it's a short text file) then I replace something in the string after that I want to create a new leaderboard.txt file in the same location or overwrite the previous leaderboard.txt text file.

Here is my code for overwriting the file, but it throws a java.lang.NullPointerException

```
package tools;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import screens.PlayMenu;


public class Leaderboard
{
    private static BufferedReader leaderboardIn;

    public static void checkLeaderBoard(int time, int currentLevel)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream filePath = Leaderboard.class
                    .getResourceAsStream("/Other/Leaderboard.txt");
            leaderboardIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(filePath));

            String input = "";
            for (int level = 1; level < currentLevel; level++)
                input = leaderboardIn.readLine() + '\n';
            String line = leaderboardIn.readLine();
            int leaderboardTime = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,
                    line.indexOf(' ')));
            if (leaderboardTime > time)
            {
                line = time + " " + PlayMenu.playerName.toUpperCase() + '\n';
                input += line;
                while ((line = leaderboardIn.readLine()) != null)
                    input += line + '\n';
                 PrintWriter fileOut = 
                           new PrintWriter(
                                 new File(Leaderboard.class.getResource("/Trial and Error/resources/Other/Leaderboard.txt").getPath()));
                fileOut.write(input);
                fileOut.close();
            }
            filePath.close();
            leaderboardIn.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a picture of where my actual text file is: 
[image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Edit
Here's the stack trace (which is also in the image)

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tools.Leaderboard.checkLeaderBoard(Leaderboard.java:39)
at entities.Player.onExit(Player.java:91)
at entities.Player.update(Player.java:38)
at screens.GameState.update(GameState.java:27)
at main.Game.update(Game.java:62)
at main.Game.run(Game.java:111)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Include the stack trace and indicate which statement in your code throws the exception.

Comment: @River I just tried that, no luck.

Comment: Ok do these tests to see what is returning null: Test `Leaderboard.class.getResource("/Trial and Error/resources/Other/Leaderboard.txt")` and that`.getPath())` to see which  (if either) returns `null`. (I'm guessing the first does, meaning it can't find the file along the path you specified.)

Comment: Actually, why are you using **different paths** for the same file at all?

Comment: @River I thought i was using the same path? Removing .getPath() and i can't compile the code.

Comment: One has the path "Other/Leaderboard.txt" the other has "/Trial and Error/resources/Other/Leaderboard.txt". I suspect your second one is returning null. Test this by taking `Leaderboard.class.getResource("/Trial and Error/resources/Other/Leaderboard.txt")` out of those constructors and printing it. (And comment out the constructors and relevant code.)

Comment: @noobycoder.. You are not using the same path... Surely `/Other/Leaderboard.txt` and `/Trial and Error/resources/Other/Leaderboard.txt` are not the same...

Comment: I've tried both and they both are the same file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see stack trace, which is pointing at `Line 39`
Please write following code and see their output.

```
Leaderboard c = new Leaderboard();
Class cls = c.getClass();

// finds resource relative to the class location
URL url = cls.getResource("/Other/Leaderboard.txt");
System.out.println("Value = " + url);

// finds resource relative to the class location
url = cls.getResource("/Trial and Error/resources/Other/Leaderboard.txt");
System.out.println("Value = " + url);
```

If last one returns `null`, then resource with the name is not found.

**Additionally,** Try following

```
Leaderboard c = new Leaderboard();
    Class cls = c.getClass();
fileOut = new PrintWriter(new File(cls.getResource("/Other/Leaderboard.txt").getPath()));
```

instead of

```
 PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new File(Leaderboard.class.getResource("/Trial and Error/resources/Other/Leaderboard.txt").getPath()));
```

Comment: ^This is the `null` testing I was trying to describe in comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would have posted this as a comment, but apparently I don't have enough reputation to do that, so...

Why not just use [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) and [`Files.write()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)?

Comment: I did use fileOut.write(input); i'm not sure about readAllLines();

Comment: No, I mean `Files`, the [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

Comment: @Pentarctagon there you go, now you can comment.